# No sound in Ubuntu 12.10 [Or any distro], mb soundcard

Tags: sound, laptop, soundcard

Integrated motherboard sound card. One day sound stopped working. No boot sound, no nothing. Laptop's microphone works.

Installed 4 different distributions, including Debian, yet no boot sound - nothing.

Help.

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem like Ubuntu specific question since you mentioned that the sound doesn't work on at least for distributions. For me, your integrated sound card is broken.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here. it seems any kernel somewhere after 3.6.4 produces severe misconfiguring of the pulseaudio client and X11 setups. the nay-sayers that said pulse was a dog, and it  would eventually bite us, were right. SuSE, Ubuntu, and Fedora 16+ all have this failure. that this has gone on for over a year also underscores the developers' total lack of concern in correcting it. it's not on anyones critical list, to my knowledge.
solution: remove pulseaudio; note: this is a code based prob, as windows 7 sound works  ;)